# Adaptive Bilateral Filter to preserve edges

Tags: c++, opencv, imagefilter

I need to be able to detect the edges of a card, currently it works when the background is non-disruptive and best when it is contrasting but still works pretty well on a non-contrasting background.

The problem occurs when the card is on a disruptive background the bilateral filter lets in too much noise and causes inaccurate edge detection.

Here is the code I am using:

```
bilateralFilter(imgGray, detectedEdges, 0, 175, 3, 0);
Canny( detectedEdges, detectedEdges, 20, 65, 3 );

dilate(detectedEdges, detectedEdges, Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8UC1));
```

The `imgGray` being the grayscale version of the original image.

Here are some tests on a disruptive background and the results (contact info distorted in all images):

Colored card:

[image]

Result:

[image]

And here is a white card:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can preserve the edges of the card no matter the background, color while removing the noise?

Comment: does canny compute the edges from grayscale image? maybe you can try working on the hue-channel?

Comment: I tried to use the hue channel as input for bilateral filter and canny, which gives very good results for the blue card, but bad results for the white card. But I think the trick will be to consider color information in your edge detection, too!

Answer (score 1):

Find the edges using `canny` which you are already doing, then find the `contour` in image and find the suitable `rectangle using bounding box` and apply some threshold on the occupancy and the dimensions of rectangle. This should zero down to your rectangle i.e. your card edges and take it as  `ROI` on which you can further work.

Comment: Down-Voter should explain when they down-vote. This is not about my answer but it shall be better.

Comment: My think, you must explain your thinks with your codes. Because disappoint answers like yours who are searching solutions.

Comment: Lol, you may be right Can, but I don't want to spoon feed, these are very basic constructs and can be found on google easily. Anyway, good day :).

Comment: +1 for Pervez Alam. This answer is totally fine and there is no magic single-line API for such question. Some code would have been a plus but if you know OpenCV (and the guy who is asking knows about it...), it's not very difficult to implement canny + contour + bouding box. As for Can Urek, start learning English before commentating because your post is incomprehensible...!